# angularjs changes checkbox value from integer to boolean

Tags: angularjs

I have some kind of repeat (its actually the grid-api that loops among elements).
For each row I print a checkbox.
In grid-api the element is referred as row.entity. Which is a json object.

Now, Im setting the ng-model equals to the id, like this:

```
ng-model="row.entity.id"
```

I also print that ID on the screen, and it is a number.
The ng-click looks like this:

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.addToQueue(row.entity.id, $event)"
```

The function that handles the ng-click is this:

```
scope.addToQueue = function(id, $event){
     var element = angular.element($event.target);
     console.log("element:",element);
     console.log("id:",id);
  }
```

The problem is that on the screen a number is printed. But as soon as I click in the checkbox, the value becomes a boolean, true or false.
How can I get the actual number?
In the console it is the same problem. The boolean is printed.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `data-ng-true-value` and its counterpart `data-ng-false-value`.

E.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.id"  data-ng-true-value="1" data-ng-false-value="0" />
```

> This is also very well documented on their documentation page. Take a
>   closer look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D).